# I want to get count of communication logged in weekly then its previous week and so on in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have tried this -

```
declare @maxD datetime 
select @maxD= max(loggingdate) FROM CommunicationLogs 

SELECT Count(loggingdate),@maxD FROM CommunicationLogs 
WHERE loggingdate  BETWEEN (@maxD - 6) AND @maxD and clientid ='20154'

4   2017-08-21 11:18:24.930
```

The above output means communication logged before 2017-08-21 11:18:24.930 and before its 7 days are 4. But the problem is its specific to max date. I want to get same result for all the logged date.

I tried but giving wrong data-

```
SELECT COUNT(id),loggingdate FROM CommunicationLogs 
WHERE loggingdate  BETWEEN (loggingdate - 6) AND loggingdate and clientid ='20154'
group by loggingdate
ORDER BY loggingdate desc
```

The sql data is -

```
31935   2017-08-21 11:18:24.930
31936   2017-08-21 00:00:00.000
31933   2017-08-18 14:53:03.707
31934   2017-08-18 00:00:00.000
31924   2017-08-10 12:06:00.397
31918   2017-07-26 00:00:00.000
31919   2017-07-26 00:00:00.000
31920   2017-07-26 00:00:00.000
31921   2017-07-26 00:00:00.000
31922   2017-07-26 00:00:00.000
31923   2017-07-26 00:00:00.000
31898   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31899   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31900   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31901   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31902   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31903   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31904   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31905   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31906   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31907   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31908   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31909   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31910   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31911   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31912   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31913   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31914   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31915   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31916   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31917   2017-07-25 00:00:00.000
31889   2017-07-24 00:00:00.000
31890   2017-07-24 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: What is the "wrong data" you are getting from your current query, and what would the "right data" be, instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this , hope it helps , or give you and idea.

**SQL Server 2005**

--to get the logging data weekly depends on Maximum Date

```
select Count(loggingDate),max(loggingDate) from (select CommunicationLogs.id,CommunicationLogs.loggingDate,cast(DATEDIFF(day,loggingDate,maxLoggingDate)/7 as int)WeekGroup from CommunicationLogs
cross apply  (select max(loggingDate) maxLoggingDate  from  CommunicationLogs)maxData)weekGroupData
group by  WeekGroup
```

--to get the logging data weekly depends on Maximum Date for each id

```
select id,Count(*),max(loggingDate) from 
(select CommunicationLogs.id,CommunicationLogs.loggingDate,cast(DATEDIFF(day,loggingDate,maxLoggingDate)/7 as int)WeekGroup from CommunicationLogs
    left join (select id,max(loggingDate) maxLoggingDate  from  CommunicationLogs group by id) maxData 
     on maxData.id=CommunicationLogs.id
)weekGroupData
group by id,WeekGroup
```

**SQL server 2008+** you can use CTE clause to make it more readable

--to get the logging data weekly depends on Maximum Date

```
with maxData as
(
select max(loggingDate) maxLoggingDate  from  CommunicationLogs
),
weekGroupData as(
select CommunicationLogs.id,CommunicationLogs.loggingDate,cast(DATEDIFF(day,loggingDate,maxLoggingDate)/7 as int)WeekGroup from CommunicationLogs
cross apply  maxData  
)
select Count(loggingDate),max(loggingDate) from weekGroupData
group by  WeekGroup
```

--to get the logging data weekly depends on Maximum Date for each id

```
with maxData as
(
select id, max(loggingDate) maxLoggingDate  from  CommunicationLogs
group by id
),
weekGroupData as(
select CommunicationLogs.id,CommunicationLogs.loggingDate,cast(DATEDIFF(day,loggingDate,maxLoggingDate)/7 as int)WeekGroup from CommunicationLogs
left join  maxData on maxData.id=CommunicationLogs.id
)
select id,Count(*),max(loggingDate) from weekGroupData
group by id,WeekGroup
```